# How do you add "ListView" to Visual Studio Toolbox in Silverlight?

Tags: xaml, silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I want to use "ListView" on my xaml file but I can't seem to find it. How can I add it and what reference(s) do I need to install in order to use it?

[current toolbox contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2W4N.png)

Comment: I've managed to find it however, I still can't use it because it is disabled. How can I enable it? https://imgur.com/Ez98Y1C

Comment: Are you using Silverlight or WPF? Your screenshot shows Silverlight controls.

Comment: its silverlight. I'm sorry